# Why Last-Modified can be strong validator

Tags: http, web, networking, http-headers, last-modified

I read [RFC 7232](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232), which describes the Last-Modified time as below:

> A Last-Modified time, when used as a validator in a request, is implicitly weak unless it is possible to deduce that it is strong, using the following rules:
>
> 1. The validator is about to be used by a client in an If-Modified-Since, If-Unmodified-Since, or If-Range header field, because the client has a cache entry for the associated representation, and
> 2. That cache entry includes a Date value, which gives the time when the origin server sent the original response, and
> 3. The presented Last-Modified time is at least 60 seconds before the Date value.

My question is, "Why can those three conditions that Last-Modified support mean it can be strong validator?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section you quoted goes on to say:

> This method relies on the fact that if two different responses were
> sent by the origin server during the same second, but both had the
> same `Last-Modified` time, then at least one of those responses would
> have a `Date` value equal to its `Last-Modified` time.  The arbitrary
> 60-second limit guards against the possibility that the `Date` and
> `Last-Modified` values are generated from different clocks or at
> somewhat different times during the preparation of the response.

Say that we have two representations of a resource, *A* being the older version and *B* being the newer version. If they were both modified in the same second then they could both be served with the same `Last-Modified` time. So if all we have to go on is the `Last-Modified` header we don't know whether the representation is *A* or *B*. That's what makes `Last-Modified` a weak validator.

But let's say the cache entry also has an associated `Date` field, and that it's later than `Last-Modified`. We can now safely assume that the cache entry is *B*, the version that was current as of the `Date` time. Since we now know which version is represented by the cache entry we can treat `Last-Modified` as a strong validator.

(Note that [the most recent standards](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#lastmod.comparison) use 1 second instead of 60.)